# After I've downgraded my wamp PHP version to 5.2.11, how can I get Apache to start?

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to run a PHP application full of depracted `ereg` calls.  I got the wampserver extension to switch from PHP 5.3.10 to 5.2.11, where that function is still valid, but when I try to start my services Apache won't start.  I'm using Apache 2.2.11, PHP 5.2.11, and MySQL 5.5.20 on Windows 7 x64.  The `index.php` page I'm trying to load comes up when I use PHP 5.3.10, albeit with a lot of errors about my `ereg` functions.

I get that I can go through all my PHP files and update the code to modern usage, but shouldn't I be able to use wampserver's PHP version extensions, since they're offered?

I've tried copying .dll's from `/wamp/bin/php/php5.2.11/` directly into `/wamp/bin/` but it looks like the installer for the 5.2.11 extension had taken care of that already.  It also seems to have updated `php.ini` during install.

The Apache error log shows zero activity when I try to start wamp services.  Not even notices.

I'm pretty new to Apache and PHP so I'm not sure what relevant info I could paste from `php.ini` or `httpd.conf` but if there's anything in either of those that you think would be helpful to work toward a solution, let me know and I'll paste it.

Comment: What do you get when you run `httpd -t` on the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ereg` function was "depreciated" as of PHP 5.3... Depreciated does not mean it was removed, all it means is that every time it's used, a "notice" (not error) message will be logged (and in some cases displayed on screen). That is, it's still valid in PHP 5.3. And I don't believe it was removed in PHP 5.4 if memory is correct. I think it will only be removed in PHP 6.

All you have to do is configure your php.ini settings to not log or display the `E_DEPRECATED notice`.

Here are the **php.ini** lines from my **WampDeveloper Pro** set up, just find the same directives in **WampServer** and adjust...

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = On
```

The first line will use all levels, and then remove the notices, depreciated, and strict-coding levels.

That last line you might or might-not want to be On or Off depending on if this is a dev system or a production system (security reasons).

You can also just leave it all as-is, and not log repeat messages ... that way you still know what's going via the logs, but they are not filled up with the same message over and over:

ignore_repeated_errors = On

**But whatever you do, don't use PHP 5.2, it's full of bugs, performance, compatibility, and security problems.**